# Nullability and LiveData with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I want to use LiveData with Kotlin and have values that should not be null. How do you deal with this? Perhaps a wrapper around LiveData? Searching for good patterns here ..
As an example:

```
class NetworkDefinitionProvider : MutableLiveData<NetworkDefinition>() {
    val allDefinitions = mutableListOf(RinkebyNetworkDefinition(), MainnetNetworkDefinition(), RopstenNetworkDefinition())

    init {
        value = allDefinitions.first()
    }

    fun setCurrent(value: NetworkDefinition) {
        setValue(value)
    }
}
```

I know value will not be null when accessing - but I will always have to check for null or have these ugly !!'s around.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I created an extension property. It's not super pretty, but it *is* pretty straightforward.

```
val <T> LiveData<T>.valueNN
    get() = this.value!!
```

Usage

```
spinner.loading = myLiveData.valueNN.homeState.loading
```

I'm not sold on appending "NN" as a good naming convention, but that's beyond the scope of the question :)

Comment: Don't do this.  Simply force-unwrapping the underlying value is dangerous because `this.value` _can_ be null.  Only when you enforce non-nullability in the _setters_ can you safely force-unwrap like the other answers suggest.

Comment: @Weikardzaena From the OP: "I know value will not be null when accessing". 
Although what I did was to subclass `LiveData` and have a private inner `MutableLiveData` so there is no way that any outside classes can change the value of my `LiveData` to `null`.

Answer (score 13):

I little improve [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49324877/4059849) The Lucky Coder. This implementation cannot accept null values at all.

```
class NonNullMutableLiveData<T: Any>(initValue: T): MutableLiveData<T>() {

    init {
        value = initValue
    }

    override fun getValue(): T {
        return super.getValue()!!
    }

    override fun setValue(value: T) {
        super.setValue(value)
    }

    fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, body: (T) -> Unit) {
        observe(owner, Observer<T> { t -> body(t!!) })
    }

    override fun postValue(value: T) {
        super.postValue(value)
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thats excellent, thanks for posting this! The AS linter complained about the overridden fun's not actually doing anything, which made me think of wrapping the setValue and postValue in value.let {...} to prevent null values being set into the LiveData.

Comment: Just playing devil's advocate, but are you absolutely sure that `getValue()` is guaranteed to return a non-null?  Obviously with this implementation there's no way a client could _set_ the value to `null`, but is there anything internally within `LiveData` that could possibly null the value?

Comment: One of the problems with this approach is that `Observer` will allways be called right away when observed. In the standard `LiveData` implementation, it won't be called until `value` is set the first time, but in this example `value` is always set right away.
@Weikardzaena AFAIK that won't be the case since value is set intially

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this is the best solution but this is what I came up with and what I use:

```
class NonNullLiveData<T>(private val defaultValue: T) : MutableLiveData<T>() {

    override fun getValue(): T = super.getValue() ?: defaultValue

    fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, body: (T) -> Unit) {
        observe(owner, Observer<T> {
            body(it ?: defaultValue)
        })
    }
}
```

Creating the field:

```
val string = NonNullLiveData("")
```

And observing it:

```
viewModel.string.observe(this) {
    // Do someting with the data
}
```

Comment: The downside of this is that if somebody DOES put a `null` into your `NonNullLiveData`, you emit to your observers a value that's completely wrong (the `defaultValue`). 
Depends maybe on your situation, but I'd rather have a crash if someone puts a null into a non-null place.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an extension for LifecycleOwner

```
fun <T> LifecycleOwner.observe(liveData: LiveData<T?>, lambda: (T) -> Unit) {
    liveData.observe(this, Observer { if (it != null) lambda(it) })
}
```

and then in your fragment/activity

```
observe(liveData) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
normalLiveData
  .nonNull()
  .observe(this, { result -> 
    // result is non null now
  })
```

There is an article about it. https://medium.com/@henrytao/nonnull-livedata-with-kotlin-extension-26963ffd0333

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
class NotNullLiveData<T : Any>
constructor(private val default: T) : MediatorLiveData<T>() {
    override fun getValue(): T {
        return super.getValue() ?: default
    }

    override fun setValue(value: T) {
        super.setValue(value)
    }
}

@MainThread
fun <T : Any> mutableLiveDataOfNotNull(initValue: T): NotNullLiveData<T> {
    val liveData = NotNullLiveData(initValue)
    liveData.value = initValue
    return liveData
}

@MainThread
fun <T> mutableLiveDataOf(initValue: T): MutableLiveData<T> {
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<T>()
    liveData.value = initValue
    return liveData
}


fun <T : Any> LiveData<T?>.toNotNull(default: T): NotNullLiveData<T> {
    val result = NotNullLiveData(default)
    result.addSource(this) {
        result.value = it ?: default
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using strings is simple by using this way:

```
val someLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
...
someLiveData.value.orEmpty()
```

And you will get actual value if set or an empty string instead of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked [The Lucky Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5231268/the-lucky-coder)'s answer. Regarding the danger on trying to set a null value, I think we should throw an exception for this (similar to what [David Whitman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622788/david-whitman) was pointing):

```
class NonNullLiveData<T>(private val defaultValue: T) : MutableLiveData<T>() {

override fun getValue(): T = super.getValue() ?: defaultValue

override fun setValue(value: T) {
    if(value != null) {
        super.setValue(value)
    }
    else throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set a null value to this Type. Use normal MutableLiveData instead for that.")
}

override fun postValue(value: T) {
    if(value != null) {
        super.postValue(value)
    }
    else throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot post a null value to this Type. Use normal MutableLiveData instead for that.")
}

fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, body: (T) -> Unit) {
    observe(owner, Observer<T> {
        body(it ?: defaultValue)
    })
}
```

}

Now the value in the MutableLiveData will never be null, so that the class would not be used in a way it's not intended.