# Confused about when Kotlin infers a platform type

Tags: generics, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Messing around with the following example code made me realize I'm confused about when Kotlin infers a platform type:

```
inline fun <reified U, V> LiveData<U>.map(crossinline f: (U) -> V): LiveData<V> {
    val result = MediatorLiveData<V>()
    result.addSource(this) { u -> // u: U!
        if (u is U) {
            result.value = f(u)
        }
    }
    return result
}

val x = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val y = x.map { it + 1 }

x.value = 1 // ok
x.value = null // will eventually crash from doing null + 1
```

My hope was that this use of reified+crossinline would prevent the `map` function from calling `f` when `u` is `null`, because it would check if `null is Int`. Interestingly though, the `null` sneaks past the check.

I thought I must be misunderstanding how reified+crossinline works, but it seems that what's actually at issue is type inference: `U` seems to be inferred as `Int!`, not `Int`. For example, manually specifying `map`'s type parameters gets things to work:

```
val y = x.map<Int, Int> { it + 1 }
```

So. Why was Kotlin infering a platform type above? (After all, `x` has inferred type `MutableLiveData<Int>`, not `MutableLiveData<Int!>`.) Is there a way to not infer a platform type, aside from doing the inference yourself?

Answer (score 2):

The first question you should ask, before you go anywhere near Kotlin's complexities like reified generics, is: why can I do this?

```
val x = MutableLiveData<Int>()
x.value = null
```

and the answer to *that* is rooted in the fact that `MutableLiveData` is written in Java, not Kotlin.

If you wrote this class in Kotlin:

```
class MyKotlinClass<T: Any> {
    lateinit var value: T
}
```

and then tried to do this:

```
val x = MyKotlinClass<Int>()
x.value = null
```

then it wouldn't compile. That's because you've defined the type as the non-nullable `Any`.

But imagine writing such a generic class in Java, where `Any` is `Object` and you can't define nullability on anything really, except by providing annotations:

```
class ExampleJavaClass<T> {
    public ExampleJavaClass(T param) {

    }

    static ExampleJavaClass getStringInstance() {
        return new ExampleJavaClass<String>(null);
    }
}
```

That's allowed. So to permit fully compatible interop with Java, Kotlin has to assume that nulls are OK. Unfortunately for you, it's invisible.

Until someone produces a Kotlin-specific implementation of LiveData that will tighten this up, you have to deal with null, or you can write one yourself, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49592114/635075). I wouldn't necessarily encourage writing your own - there may be adverse consequences.

In many cases, if you own the Java code, you can improve the interop situation by annotating the Java to define nullability, e.g. `@NonNull`. However it doesn't look like you can do this using the existing annotations on type parameters.

Comment: About the term "platform type", I think that's the official one: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't know that was an official term and thought you might have meant Android or whatever.